# Detect whether a contract can handle ERC20 or not

Tags: solidity

How to detect whether a contract can handle ERC20 or not. I have a scenario where I have to send royalties to contracts but how can I know if that contract can handle ERC20 tokens? There is an ERC721Receiver interface for the ERC721 standard that I can implement and that other contracts can use to check if the contract can handle ERC721 or not but I didn't find a such thing for ERC20.

By “handle” I mean that the contract can withdraw tokens and tokens are not locked in it.

Answer (score 1):

It's unclear what you mean by "handle", but assuming you mean "react to an ERC-20 transfer", this is not possible.

The ERC-20 standard did not specify callbacks (a.k.a. hooks), unlike other token standards such as [ERC-777](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-777).

Comment: Hey! Thank you for your reply. Basically, I mean that I'd like to be sure that receiving contract can withdraw tokens by sending them to another account and that tokens are not locked in the contract.

Comment: So basically, the external contract has to have a function like "transfer" or "withdraw" where it calls the token's contract function "transfer"

Comment: This is not possible. There's an infinite amount of ways in which a withdraw functionality can be implemented in a Turing-complete system like Ethereum.

Comment: What you may actually want is a way to recover the ERC-20 tokens if they end up in the wrong contract? take a look at my [`ERC20Recover`](https://github.com/paulrberg/prb-contracts/blob/bcd92e2541943f00aadfec9acfa6245c158f95ab/src/token/erc20/ERC20Recover.sol) contract.